# tsung jabber/xmpp request message to a single node

Tags: erlang, xmpp, load-testing, tsung

i would like to send XMPP-Messages to specific XMPP-User. Unfortunately the tsung request "jabber" with typ "chat" only allows broadcast messages to all online users (see below).

```
<request><jabber type="chat" ack="no_ack" size="16" destination="online"/></request>
```

Is there a way to send XMPP-Messages to a single user?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Documentation seems to indicate that it [does support XMPP messages to single user](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/features.html#jabber-xmpp-related-features).

I haven't found any documentation about message types, but there is a source code, which also indicates that [multiple ways of addressing users are available](https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/src/tsung/ts_jabber_common.erl#L97). I don't want to mislead you about particular types, just read the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul. It seems like there are a few undocumented destination types like "random" or "unique".

For now i went with raw xml which was also working for my case.